# How to pass JSON string when receiving Web api method is accepting strongly typed parameter using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to figure out how to POST JSON in a string format to a web api 2 method that accepts strongly typed object in c# consuming application.

Here is my POST method signature
I understand that the api is not truly REST full, but it is maintained by an external vendor team and I don't have much control over it.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("jobs/isrunning")]
public IHttpActionResult IsJobRunning(JobArguments jobArguments)
{
   // some logic

   return Ok(true);
}
```

Here is how JobArguments class looks like

```
public class JobArguments
{
    public JobArguments()
    {
        TrackingIds = new List<int();
    }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<int> TrackingIds { get; set; }
    public string CostCenter { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the class where I am invoking above api. Assume that I don't have access to JobArguments type here. All I have is JSON string representation of the JobArguments object.

```
public bool CheckIfJobIsRunning()
{
   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient("appurl");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string jobArguments = @"{ ""JobId"": 10, ""Code"": ""EB430"", 
    ""CostCenter"": ""XYZ"" }"; // assume this is coming from database.

    var result = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/jobs/isrunning", 
                                            jobArguments).Result;
    return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
}
```

I have removed unnecessary code and error handling to keep this example simple.

When this api call executes, the IsJobRunning method is receiving null jobArguments parameter.

I am a beginner, so don't know what I am doing wrong. Appreciate any help I can get to solve this issue.

**UPDATE**: Corrected the IsJobRunning method signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content is already JSON just send it as it is from the data store

For example

```
static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient("appurl");
public async Task<bool> CheckIfJobIsRunning(){
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
       new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var jobArguments = //Assuming the JSON came from database

    var content = new StringContent( jobArguments, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/jobs/isrunning", content);

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
    return result;
}
```

The Web API action should also use `[FromBody]` attribute to tell the model binder on the server where to look for the data to bind the parameter

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("jobs/isrunning")]
public IHttpActionResult IsJobRunning([FromBody]JobArguments jobArguments) {
   // some logic

   return Ok(true);
}
```

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Ok I mis-read will update. No need to the anonymous object if it is already stored as JSON

Comment: So If I understand correctly, In order to use StringContent at the consumer side, the api Method parameter must be decorated with [FromBody] ?

Comment: @jbl I Fixed the answer. Had some mistakes from all the editing.

Comment: thank you. I will go thru the parameter binding reference to understand how it works. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @jbl glad to help.